# How to achieve `pl.col("code").apply(lambda x: x+"88" if len(x)<=2 else x)` with pure expr logic in Polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

I use `pl.col("code").apply(lambda x: x+"88" if len(x)<=2 else x)` in a `with_columns` to work with some str. But I think it is slow because it import some python logic. Is there some way to achieve that with pure polars expr logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested.

```py
pl.when(pl.col("code").str.lengths() <= 2)
    .then(pl.concat_str(pl.col("code"), pl.lit("88")))
    .otherwise(pl.col("code"))
```

Comment: This works, you can also just do `pl.col('code') + '88'` instead of using `pl.concat_str`